# Creating a Google Calendar Event with Google Sheets script has Errors

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm close, but my logic just isn't quite working.  I am able to run the code below within Google Sheets Scripts to create a calendar event for each row in the sheet.  I am trying to get it to only create an event when a new row is entered and to only read the spreadsheet until it comes to the first column/row being empty/null. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cUG5.png)

Here is the associated code:

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('dentaldigitaldesign.bkp@gmail.com');

var startRow = 100;  // First row of data to process - 100 exempts my header row and adds to the case number count.
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows-1, numColumns);
var data = dataRange.getValues();

var complete = "TRUE";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  var row = data[i];
  var caseID = row[0]; //Case ID Number
  var patient = row[4]; //Patient Name
  var doctor = row[5];  //Doctor
  var contact = row[14]; //Doctor contact info
  var tooth = row[15]; //Tooth number
  var shade = row[10]; //Tooth Shade
  var notes = row[8];  //Notes
  var callNotes = row[7]; //Call notes if there are any
  var timeStamp = new Date (row[2]); //Retrieve the timestamp field
  // year as 4 digits (YYYY)
  var year = timeStamp.getFullYear();
  // month as 2 digits (MM)
  var month = ("0" + (timeStamp.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

  // date as 2 digits (DD)
  var day = ("0" + timeStamp.getDate()).slice(-2);
  
  var dueDate = new Date(month + day, + year);  //Due  date
  var rDate = new Date(row[2]-1); //Remind date
  var caseComplete = row[3]; //Case marked as complete
 
  if (caseComplete !== complete && caseID !== null) {
    var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, numColumns);
    calendar.createEvent(patient, rDate, rDate, {
      description: doctor + '\r' + patient + '\r' + contact + '\r' + dueDate + '\r' + tooth + '\r' + shade + '\r' + notes + '\r' + callNotes
    });
  
    currentCell.setValue(complete);
  }
}
}
```

When these events are created, they are all created for 8:59am.  Ideally, I could do a check on the calendare if an event is set for that time, a new event is added immediately after. (perhaps in 15min or 30min slots).  For now it works well for me to get the reminders on cases that are due, but eventually an invite to the doctor for them to know the due date might work well, too.

I can also use help in formatting the description field as it is not pushing the return value and everything is on one line.

And finally, the script continues to run on numerous fields beyond the scope of the desired rows, ultimately ending up with the script failing because too many event attempts are created in too short a time. (all the attempts with fields that are empty do not result in any events being created, but it is a resouce issue....and who knows maybe Google eventually blocks me?)

I appreciate any help that can be offered.

Here is the link to the Google Sheet.  No data on it is sensitive as it is only test data:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M9qYzSl1PnRv-GehHEYvpiag15UI_GjnanA0wgA4xmg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you please provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information?

Comment: Here is the sheet.  It is not sensitive as it is only in development with test data. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M9qYzSl1PnRv-GehHEYvpiag15UI_GjnanA0wgA4xmg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code, causing this expression to always return `true`, so that the script tries to create an event for each row:

```
if (caseComplete !== complete && caseID !== null) {
```

#### Empty string !== null:

You want to check whether the cell in column A is empty (that is, whether its value is [an empty string](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())), and to do that you are comparing its value to [null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null). `null` is not the same as an empty string, so the following expression will always be `true` (a cell value never returns `null`):

```
caseID !== null
```

You should be comparing this to an empty string. For example, like this:

```
caseID !== ""
```

So the `if` statement should be:

```
if (caseComplete !== complete && caseID !== "") {
```

#### Wrong complete column:

Once an event has been created, you want to set the corresponding cell in `D` to `TRUE`. You're not doing that, since you specify the last column in the sheet (`numColumns`) when setting the `currentCell`:

```
var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, numColumns);
```

Because of this, the value in `D` never changes to `TRUE`, so `caseComplete !== complete` is always `true`.

You should specify the correct column index for `D` instead, which is `4`. It should be like this:

```
var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 4);
```

**Edit**: Also, the retrieved value for cell with checked checkboxes is the boolean `true`, and you're trying to compare it with the string `TRUE`. Because of this, this condition is not working correctly. Please change:

```
var complete = "TRUE";
```

To

```
var complete = true;
```

#### Wrong number of rows in source range:

You want to get the value from row `100` till the last one in the sheet. In this case, the total number of rows in the range should be the last row (`numRows`) minus the first row in the range (`startRow`) plus one (`numRows - startRow + 1`). The `dataRange` should be defined like this instead:

```
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows - startRow + 1, numColumns);
```

#### Reference:

- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null)

Comment: Thank you.  I see the errors with the if statement.  Regarding the change of the 'Complete' field, I do not want to do that programmatically, but will be manually entered when the case is complete.  The code just needs to check if it is complete (manually) and then skip to the next row.  The final 'complete' statement was the original code that I had found and had no real negative effect, so I left it.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: With that said, when the checkbox is checked 'Complete' (giving a value of TRUE), by expectation is that the IF / AND statement would prove false and the code would be skipped for that row.  I want to avoid duplicate creations of events.  And for some reason, the final row in my current spreadsheet does not result in a new event despite being unchecked.

Comment: @JeremiahHolder `With that said, when the checkbox is checked 'Complete' (giving a value of TRUE), by expectation is that the IF / AND statement would prove false and the code would be skipped for that row. I want to avoid duplicate creations of events.`. So that's working as expected, right?

Comment: @JeremiahHolder `And for some reason, the final row in my current spreadsheet does not result in a new event despite being unchecked.`: Does this last row have column A populated, so that the code enters the `IF` block?

Comment: @JeremiahHolder Just noticed the problem about the checkboxes. The value for the check checkboxes is the boolean `true`, while you are comparing it with the string `TRUE`. To solve this, set `var complete = true;` instead of `var complete = "TRUE";`.

Comment: @JeremiahHolder I updated my answer with this latest finding, I hope this is working for you now.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a shot.  It was a bit confusing as the Sheet shows the value in that field as TRUE.